# Can I use a for loop to generate field names inside a django model class

Tags: python, django

Can I use a for loop to generate field names inside a django model class.
Example
In the below example Task will be another model class written inside the same models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.Charfield(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name

class subtask(models.Model):
    subtask_list = tasks.objects.all()
    for subtask in subtask_list:
        subtask.task_name = models.FloatField(default=0.0, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't do this. It would mean that each time a `Task` is added, you need to make migrations (to add an extra field), migrate the database, and restart it.

Comment: What you are basically looking for is a `ManyToManyField` with a `through=...` model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Comment: I did this by using a manytoone field initially but the subtask will be coming as a dropdown in the database. When ever I am creating a object to this I want to be able to store more than one subtask for it but a many to one  field is not allowing me to do that.

Comment: Also adding a task would not be a problem as this is more or less a fixed list so the number of tasks will not change.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want your `Task` to have a zero or more `Subtask`. Am I right?
If so, this is actually a `Many-to-one` relation between `Task` and `Subtask` and can be implemented as below:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.Charfield(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name

class Subtask(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This way, any number of `Subtask` can be related to a `Task` by carrying it's pk as a foreign key.

For more info read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: I did this but the subtask will be coming as a dropdown in the database. When ever I am creating a object to this I want to be able to store more than one subtask for it but a many to one  field is not allowing me to do that

Comment: with this structure you should be able to create as many subtasks as you want for a single task

Comment: the drop down is to select the related task when creating the subtask

Comment: agreed, but I am unable to store more than 1 subtask into the object using this method. My requirement is to be able to store more than one subtask with multiple values for each